# How to protect my pc from netcut users in a network

Tags: networking

I am Ubuntu user and there is no Windows in my machine. In my college network some Windows guy they are using netcut and blocking us not to use internet and I searched to defend it and I found netcut-defender but it works in only Windows. So how can I get rid of this problem ? (It's wired network)

Comment: Please asjust the tags on this question.  `netcat` has nothing to do with this "netcut" utility, which some cursory Googling leads me to understand it to be a TCP/IP and ARP scanner and MAC address spoofer.

Comment: Contact network administrator and describe the problem. (works on Windows and Linux!)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use TuxCut to conter the attack? Not really a defend mechanism, but maybe it helps.

Comment: I installed(TuxCut) but it is not working properly

Answer (score -1):

use arpwatch. it's a free linux utitlity to prevent any arp poisoning attacks on your system.

[Link to ArpWatch](http://www.tecmint.com/monitor-ethernet-activity-in-linux/)